# How to catch exceptions of JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

The string I have to parse comes from a `FileReader()`, it may be the content of a valid json file or it may be invalid (eg a script.js) ...

The problem is that `try/catch` doesn't seem to work with `JSON.parse()` ?

The following code doesn't catch de exception `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` with an invalid file.

```
try
{
    var json = JSON.parse( content );
    ..
}
catch (e)
{
    ..
}
```

To make a first validation I test the 1st character with `( content.substr(0, 1) === '{' )` but I suppose it's insufficient.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

EDIT: This question was asked by mistake.

Comment: `try{var json = JSON.parse('test');}catch(e){console.log('caught');}` works for me. Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: According to mdn, JSON.parse should throw a SyntaxError exception. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 13):

try-catch does work with `JSON.parse`. Try the following in your browser console or use SO's snippet feature:

```js
try{ 
  JSON.parse("b") 
} catch(e) { 
  document.writeln("Caught: " + e.message)
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way, showing the returned error message.

Answer (score 4):

The `try..catch` block does work with `JSON.parse`, you're probably doing something else wrong. Try running this snippet to see it does indeed work:

```js
var unexpectedJSON = '{a}';
try {
    JSON.parse(unexpectedJSON);
}
catch (e) {
    alert("Unexpected value in JSON"); 
}
```