# How to beautify JSON in a text area?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to beautify JSON in text area but I'm unable to do it.

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="" style="width:100%"> 
                                                       
${data}

</textarea>

<button onclick="prettyPrint()">Pretty Print</button>
```

And, this is the script which I'm using to beautify the JSON in text area.

```js
function prettyPrint() {
    var ugly = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
    var obj = JSON.parse(ugly);
    var pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = pretty;
}
```

I think `JSON.stringify` is not working or I don't know what is wrong in my code.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I just tested it. Your code works (for me on FF at least). Are you getting any errors in your devtools console?

Comment: use `value`, not `innerHTML`: `document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = pretty;`

Comment: @traynor strangely the code still works with `innerHTML`. But you're right that `value` is the correct method.

Comment: @Andy, true, on first call, but afterwards it won't, if you enter value manually

Comment: @Andy, right, value should be used, but it will work with `innerHTML` like you said, but the value has to be _read_ and set with `innerHTML` as well, it's inherited, the property is not mentioned..: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: @traynor it will not work it is showing in console that there are some whitespace in my textarea. Is there any way to remove whitespace form textarea, then beautify that particular JSON.

Comment: it's not clear what the problem is, and also what is `${data}`. Most likely, JSON is not valid, so try adding an error handler, see: [How to catch exceptions of JSON.parse()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516867/how-to-catch-exceptions-of-json-parse)

Comment: you should edit your post to include all relevant information with reproducible example, if the suggestions don't solve your problem

Comment: @Andy it will beautify only 1 json data but I have multiple json to beautify. After, beautify 1 json it will add some white space in that text area and that's why it will not beautify json.